# Immediately-called closures in Swift

Tags: closures, swift

Does anyone know how to create an immediately-called closure in Swift? I tried my hand at it but I don't think the feature is supported:

```swift
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

var initialize: () = { () -> () in
    var str = "Hello World"

    struct Example {
        var myString: String
    }
}()

println("Hello")
println(str)
Example(myString: "Hello World")
```

I get the following errors:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'str'
Use of unresolved identifier 'Example'
```

[image: ImmediatelyCalledClosuresSwift]

EDIT:

::FACEPALM:: I just realized this is working as expected: anything outside of the scope of that initialize function isn't available to the program, naturally. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `str` that is declared within the scope of the closure, outside of its scope. That will never work.

Also, please note that you are not actually capturing the closure in the initialize variable. In swift, the assignment of variables does not return anything (as indicated by the `()`). The only exception to that is in the case of `if let` and `if var`

So you can create an immediately called closure but you cannot capture it in a variable.

Comment: I'm confused by your statement that, "...the assignment of variables does not return anything (as indicated by the ())". The OP never tries to use the return value of an assignment as a side-effect. What were you trying to explain?

Comment: He declared `initialize` as type `()` which is basically an empty type. The fact that the code compiles, shows that calling the closure is returning nothing. He is not capturing the closure in the initialize variable.

Comment: Of course not. He's capturing its *return value*, which is `()`.

Comment: I think I see what point you're trying to make, but it's oddly worded.

Comment: Right, I felt that he thought that he might be capturing the closure itself. You may be right that it could be worded better

Comment: Cool. Yeah, I just wanted to make it clear that he *could* capture a reference to the closure, of course. For example: `var initialize: () -> () = { () -> () in /* */ }`

Comment: But I'm off on a tangent... :)

Answer (score 1):

The closure is being called immediately but the definitions within the braces are lost when the scope of the closure is exited. This works:

```
var str = "before"
var initialize: () = { () -> () in
    str = "Hello World"
    }()

println(str)
```